# On Error GoTo: Getting Error message-2147024809

Tags: vba, excel

I am using VBA to pull data from SAP and separate status based on if a string contains certain words. I need it to exit the loop when an error occurs as this means that there is no more data in the SAP interface and it is trying to pull something that is not there. I used this earlier in this macro with no problems however now it is acting like the on error goto command is not active and instead pops up Error message -2147024809.

Here is the 1st section where on error goto is working properly

```
'Total Number in lot loop
'========================================================
For C = 0 To 20

'Exits loop when no more are found in column
On Error GoTo No_More_In_Lot

'Use Required end column since there is always data here (C does not include the current QN)
place_holder = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").getcellvalue(C, "LTRMN") ' LTRMN=Name of column in recording

Notification_Status = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").getcellvalue(C, "STTXT")

'Exits when no more data
If place_holder = "" Then
Exit For
Else
End If

'Counts Each valid complaint
If InStr(1, Notification_Status, "BIMP") Then
'Do nothing
Else

If InStr(1, Notification_Status, "CC04") Then
'do nothing
Else
Number_In_Lot = Number_In_Lot + 1
End If
End If

Next C

No_More_In_Lot:

'Places # in lot in excel
Cells(i + 2, 8) = Number_In_Lot
```

Below that, I have the following code where on error goto is not working properly.

Does anyone see anything wrong with the code that I wrote for this?

```
'Begins separating the notification statuses
'========================================================
Number_Substantiated = 0
Number_Not_Substantiated = 0
Number_Counterfeit = 0
Number_Cancelled = 0

Current_QN = Cells(i + 2, 2)

For C = 0 To 20

'Resets the Notification Status
Notification_Status = ""

'Exits loop when no more are found in column
On Error GoTo Skip

Notification_Number = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").getcellvalue(C, "QMNUM")

If Current_QN = Notificaiton_Number Then
'Do nothing (To not include the current notification status in the report)
Else
'Pull Notification status
Notification_Status = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").getcellvalue(C, "STTXT") ' STTXT=Name of column in recording



If InStr(1, Notification_Status, "CC01") Then
Number_Substantiated = Number_Substantiated + 1
Else: End If

'Include the notifcation status in the report
If InStr(1, Notification_Status, "CC02") Then
Number_Not_Substantiated = Number_Not_Substantiated + 1
Else: End If

'Include the notifcation status in the report
If InStr(1, Notification_Status, "CC03") Then
Number_Counterfeit = Number_Counterfeit + 1
Else: End If

'Include the notifcation status in the report
If InStr(1, Notification_Status, "CC04") Then
Number_Cancelled = Number_Cancelled + 1
Else: End If


End If

Next C

Skip:

'Passes values to sheet
Cells(i + 2, 9) = Number_Substantiated
Cells(i + 2, 10) = Number_Not_Substantiated
Cells(i + 2, 11) = Number_Counterfeit
Cells(i + 2, 12) = Number_Cancelled
```

Comment: The error message suggests that you are doing something invalid - which can be just about anything. The first thing to try is to see if you can set the cell values the way you are doing at line starting with `Current_QN = ` in a small and clean sub.

Comment: Yes what is invalid is that I am trying to pull data when it cannot find an object to grab (end of column) The thing is that I am using this on purpose to stop the action when an error is reached. I have added to my original post and included the section above the code I first provided. It uses an identical approach in a different loop. Without the on error goto, it gives me the same error but when I use the on error goto, it does its job properly.

Comment: Ok. The next step is to reduce the code you have posted here down to a minimal example that still produces the problem.

Comment: You're not using `On Error GoTo No_More_In_Lot` correctly - when it jumps to the `No_More_In_Lot` label it won't have cleared the error flag.  You should have the error handler at the end of the code - after an `Exit Sub` and before the `End Sub` once the error has been dealt with you can `Resume No_More_In_Lot`.  The same goes for `Skip`

Comment: You don't need to write `Else:End If` - just `End If` will do.  There's also `ElseIf` rather than embedding another `If` after an `Else`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that VB has problems with the reserved keyword SKIP.

```
...
On Error GoTo Skip_
...
Skip_:
...
```

Regards, ScriptMan